# Different CSS transition for *IN* and *OUT* (or returning from transitioned state)

Tags: css, fadein, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a loading image which comes up during an Ajax load event. The image shows/hides by adding or removing a "loading" class to the body element. Currently, the loading image animates background-size from 0 to 100%, and fades in the opacity (vice versa for the 'return' transition).

I want to have the background-size transition happen instantly (not transition) on the fade out, so:

- Fade in: opacity from 0 to 1 in .2s, background size from 0 to 100% in .2s
- Fade out: opacity from 1 to 0 in .2s, background size from 100% to 0 *should happen instantly*

  ```
   #loader {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       z-index: -1;
       opacity: 0;
       -moz-opacity: 0;
       transition: all .2s ease-in-out
   }


   #loader .image {
       width: 400px;
       height: 138px;
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 2000; 
       top: 50%; 
       left: 50%; 
       margin: 0;
       background: url(assets/images/loading.png) no-repeat;
       background-size: 0 0;
       transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
       -webkit-animation: pulse 400ms ease-out infinite alternate;
       -moz-animation: pulse 400ms ease-out infinite alternate;
       -o-animation: pulse 400ms ease-out infinite alternate;
       animation: pulse 400ms ease-out infinite alternate
   }

   .loading #loader {z-index: 1000; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7)}

   .loading #loader .image {
       background-size: 100% 100%; 
       margin: -69px 0 0 -200px;
       transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out
   }
  ```

I've changed transition property for this selector `.loading #loader .image` to "opacity" rather than "all", but it still performs the background-size transition.

Does anyone know how to achieve the different fade in and fade out transitions described above with CSS?

Comment: Please add your working code as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a simplified test case:

```
div {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

div.loading {
    opacity: 1;
    background: red;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out, background 1s ease-in;
}
```

Notice how the `opacity` fades the same in and out, but the `background` only fades in, and immediately turns blue on fade out.

I used `:hover` as an example, but it should work the same when adding and removing classes with JavaScript.

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1648745)

If you'd like a more specific example please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: +1 Yes. This is the right way. Break out into classes and add/remove as needed. There are some issues with adding classes in Javascript with transitions that I go over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8213003/918414

Comment: Thanks! using transition: all was the issue. I had to break out the transition properties separated by commas like you had. I've updated my working code in the answer.

Comment: Just to be clear - the "ease-in" transition is not what is causing a fade in and snap out. It's that the transition on background only applies on hover. Once the hover is removed there is no longer a transition on the background property at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` for the 'transition out' effect, and the base selector for the 'transition in' effect:

```css
div {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 3s; /* Mouse Leave */
}

div:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: 1s; /* Mouse Enter */
}
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/obtd6nxz/15/

Brief Explanation: `:hover` rule will override the base rule, but only while hovering. As soon as your mouse leaves, the transition-out effect will continue from what your base rule declares.

Comment: A more straightforward answer for visitors to this question.