# Different css3 transition time for "into" and "return" state

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to user css3 transitions to fade the opacity of an element (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-duration.asp).

For instance, I say:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
```

Is there a way to specify a different "return to original state" time than the 2s?

I'd like to low the opacity in 2 seconds, but bring it back up in 0.5 seconds.

[CSS3 Transition: Different transition for *IN* and *OUT* (or returning from transitioned state)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944456/css3-transition-different-transition-for-in-and-out-or-returning-from-tran) seems to accomplish this but using multiple elements. Any better way?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there is a better way - http://jsfiddle.net/bJKpu/

Just specify different `transition-duration`-s for normal and hovered state:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: orange;
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}


div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Since I'm not actually using mouse commands, I'm actually changing the transition CSS with jQuery when issuing the command that takes-it-to or returns-it-from the altered state.

Comment: why do you need jquery if it works just fine without it? some people have javascript disabled, but they can't disable CSS :)

Comment: just using jquery b/c easier and I'm building a js-heavy webapp... plain javascript would work just as well.

Comment: Absolute hero, I wish I could +10 :)

Comment: x2 - works like a dream. I had to experiment a little and switch my hover and non-hover transitions around, but it works well. Thanks :) (This should be marked as the correct answer)