# Apply separate transition timing for same CSS property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an icon inside a div that I would like to fade in over x time, and fade out faster.

What I am trying to achieve is something like: `transition: opacity 1s ease-in .1s ease-out;`

So when I hover over `project`, `bottom-icons` should only `ease-in` the `opacity` to `1`, but on offhover, it should return to `opacity: 0` instantly.

What I have is:

```
.project {
  position: relative;
  &:hover {
    .bottom-icons  {
      opacity: 1 !important;
    }
  }
  .bottom-icons {
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    //other stuff
    }
```

I am trying to do this avoiding jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 Transition: Different transition for \*IN\* and \*OUT\* (or returning from transitioned state)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944456/css3-transition-different-transition-for-in-and-out-or-returning-from-tran)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your `transition` on hover, like so:

```
.project {
  position: relative;
  &:hover {
    .bottom-icons  {
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
      opacity: 1 !important;
    }
  }
  .bottom-icons {
    transition: opacity .1s ease-out;
    //other stuff
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8x184o6x/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done pretty easily.

```
.project .bottom-icons {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out; /* leaving effect */
}
.project:hover .bottom-icons {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out; /* entering effect */
}
```

(Sorry that code is in pure CSS but I find it more universal.)

Transitions can be different for normal state and `:hover` state, and this is what we’re using here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.project {
  position: relative;
  &:hover {
    .bottom-icons  {
      opacity: 1 !important;
     transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    }
  }
  .bottom-icons {
    transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    //other stuff
    }
```

Just set the icons to easy out of their normal state, and ease out of their hover state differently.

```css
.project {
      position: relative;
background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
padding: 30px;}
     
 .bottom-icons  {
       display: block;
       background: #ddd;
   padding: 5px;
          opacity: 1 ;
         transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
        }
   .project:hover .bottom-icons {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-out;

        }
```

```html
<div class="project">
  
 <div class="bottom-icons">
   xxxxx
   </div>
  
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, you can use the following things:

```
ADD transition to the hover,
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    opacity : 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
   opacity: .1;
   -moz-transition:2s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div>
</div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```