# CSS transition doesn't work when javascript added properties continuous

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

Below is a simplified version of a problem I am having with my website.

```js
function move(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.transition = "0s";
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = "100px";
  document.getElementById("box").style.transition = "2s";
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = "0px";
}
```

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="move()"></div>
```

What I want it to do is make the box instantaneously jump downwards, and then slowly move back to its starting position. I have tested each of the four lines of code inside `move()` separately and they work perfect. I just can't get them to run in one go.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8210560/6190320

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seem the code needs to delay before assigning new property that cause browser can process the request. So you need to use `setTimeout()` to solving this problem.

```js
function move(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.transition = "0s";
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = "100px";
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.transition = "2s";
    document.getElementById("box").style.top = "0px";
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="move()"></div>
```

Comment: I think I follow this. The only bit that puzzles me is why 10ms? Why not 1ms?

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers You can use 1ms if it work. I used `10ms to make sure that code work.

Comment: This solution works well. I changed it from 10ms to 1ms and nothing has broken yet. (Not that I can tell the difference. 1ms just feels like cleaner code to me.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of relying on transitions, it would be better to use `@keyframes` and `animation`, so that you don't have to use dirty tricks like changing the transition duration from 0 to actual value mid-animation to achieve the jump. Below is an example that utilizes the `@keyframes` css features:

```js
function move(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.animation = "movement 2s";
}
```

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
}
@keyframes movement {
    from {top: 100px;}
    to {top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="move()"></div>
```

Comment: I am intrigued, but why does it only work for the first click?

Comment: Also, will it work if the start and/or finish locations are determined by javascript?

Comment: It works only of first click, because once the class is added, then re-adding it does not change the css rules applied, so if nothing changes, then no animation takes place. So to work with multiple clicks you need to remove the class once the animation is done. And to change locations in javascript, you can use css variables. Solution for both problems can be found in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJqbWM