# Different behavior of transition when launched via event listener vs direct function call

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code to transition element's opacity on button press:

```js
let el = document.createElement('div')
el.className = 'thumbnail'
document.body.appendChild(el)

let show_btn = document.getElementById('show_btn')
show_btn.addEventListener('click', show_el)

function show_el() {
    el.style.opacity = 1
}
```

```css
 .thumbnail {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <body>
            <button id="show_btn">Show el</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Why will the transitiion not work once I remove the event listener and put the `show_el()` call directly under the part that creates the element?:

```js
let el = document.createElement('div')
el.className = 'thumbnail'
document.body.appendChild(el)
show_el()

function show_el() {
  el.style.opacity = 1
}
```

```css
.thumbnail {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

Also, can I make it work in such setting anyhow?

Comment: _“Why will the transitiion not work once I remove the event listener and put the show_el() call directly under the part that creates the element?”_ - because the JS part is executed as a “block”, and control is only passed back to the rendering engine _after_ it has finished. So the rendering engine does not see any _change_ in opacity happening, and therefor does not see any need to _transition_ anything either. One common workaourd is to introduce a short “delay” using a timeout or requestanimationframe.

Comment: @04FS even setting a timeout it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/wtjh7y8n/

Comment: Use `setTimeout(show_el, 0)` instead of `setTimeout(show_el(), 0)`

Comment: That’s because you’re doing it wrong. `show_el()` is a function _call_, but you want to pass the _reference_ to the function object to setTimeout. https://jsfiddle.net/627an4yw/

Comment: @04FS: Thanks, great explanation! Mind posting an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210560/css-transitions-do-not-work-when-assigned-trough-javascript basically answers this already, there’s others, too - this should rather be closed as a duplicate, then given a repeated answer.

Comment: And don't even set a timeout, simply trigger a reflow as explained in the [second answer of the linked Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997214/3702797) or [here with a more wordy explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344996/css-transition-doesnt-work-if-element-start-hidden/54348963#54348963)