# When class is added, it wont animate like i asked it to

Tags: javascript

I want to add a class to a div, in an animated way!

```js
const divnew = document.createElement("div");
    divnew.classList.add("circle");
    const beans = document.getElementById("beans");
    beans.append(divnew);
    divnew.classList.add("up");
```

```css
.circle{
    background:#FCD299;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    top:300px;
    left: 500px;
    transition:all 300ms;
}

.circle.up{
    position:relative;
    top:200px;
    left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="beans"></div>
```

as you can see, it adds a class to a div, and then i want it to add the class `up` in an animation way. But it doesnt do that. help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transitions do not work when assigned trough JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210560/css-transitions-do-not-work-when-assigned-trough-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The browser first evaluates all the javascript, and afterwards does the CSS stuff (probably glossing over some details, but that's the basic gist). So the browser just sees a `div` with both the `circle` and `up` class. To fix it, you can delay setting the `up` class, using `setTimeout` like so:

```js
const divnew = document.createElement("div");
divnew.classList.add("circle");
const beans = document.getElementById("beans");
beans.append(divnew);

setTimeout(() => {
    divnew.classList.add("up")
}, 0)
```

Even if the timeout is set to 0ms, it gets pushed to the microtask queue, which is evaluated later and thus the CSS gets updated and the browser animates the element. So you're getting the animation but it still happens instantly after creating the div.

Comment: A `setTimeout` with `0` delay will not create a microtask, in fact- if it did it wouldn't achieve the desired effect here, since all microtasks are executed immediately after the current macro task finishes, without letting anything else happen (such as rendering elements or processing DOM), if you replace your `setTimeout` with a `queueMicrotask` you'll see. `setTimeout` `0` is acceptable here- but the correct function to use is `requestAnimationFrame` which will queue the callback after style and layout and directly before the next paint (ensuring the animation starts as soon as possible)

Comment: I never really understood how`requestAnimationFrame` worked and I just knew that `setTimeout` did work. But you're right that I should be using the correct function. I'll try to use it more, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) in order to allow the element to be rendered *without* the destination class first, otherwise it doesn't know it needs to transition because the first time it's rendered it has no 'memory' of not having the class.

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("circle");

document.body.appendChild(div);

window.requestAnimationFrame(
    () => div.classList.add("animate")
);
```

```css
.circle {
    background: #FCD299;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 3000ms;
}

.circle.animate {
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Alternatively you can instead use a CSS [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and define [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) for your desired movement rather than relying on a `transition` -- this also avoids any need for JavaScript.

```css
.circle {
    background: #FCD299;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    animation: 3000ms forwards animate;
}

@keyframes animate {
    from {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    to {
        top: calc(100% - 50px);
        left: calc(100% - 50px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

(note that the `animation-fill-mode` is `forwards`, it will maintain the final value of the animated attributes, rather than just snapping back to unset when the animation finishes)